# Once again, black screen after install

Tags: boot, screen

I exhausted all suggestions on this site for this situation, in particular the cited answer. Let me elaborate:

- Tested the DVD - fine
- booted from an installation DVD and selected "Try Ubuntu" (from DVD)
- Ubuntu booted fine, I could navigate the directory tree and open files, browse the internet - everything!.
- I then clicked "Install Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS". Installation completed successfully.
- I removed the DVD media, and hit "reboot now". The boot up got stuck with a black screen and a flashing underscore cursor at line 2 or 3. screen seems to be in SVG text mode. The only signs of life were when I reinserted the DVD and operated Ubuntu from it. When doing so I could get to the HDD and see that Ubuntu is installed there. But as soon as I removed the DVD media and rebooted, the box got stuck right after the BIOS self test.
- I repeated the above steps but before rebooting, still running from the DVD, I opened the "Drivers" window. It did detect the "Intel microcode on Intel CPU" as a missing driver. I Installed it (where? In memory? on HDD? I have no idea where to look!)
- I then rebooted again. The same result - black screen with a flashing cursor.
- Assuming it is waiting for my password I typed the password blindly, no response whatsoever. I then tried typing my User's name and password, nothing! ALT/Right-arrow then ALT/left arrow - no response.

**Now what??? Please help...**

Comment: Boot with nomodeset after install.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: @Pilot6: It never gets to the screen where I can choose manual boot, then F6. and I read that post you refer to through and through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well folks,

The culprit was my RAID Mirror volume. As per [Shlomi Fish](http://www.shlomifish.org) advice, once I dismantle the RAID into two separate disk volumes, all went well and no boot up problems.

Thanks for all your help,

Meir